# Sorting Array in c#

Tags: c#

I want to sort the array list to find out the same last names and it should be in an alphabetical order using c#.

```
string[] iniArray = { "M Facci", "D Thornton", "B Luke", "S Tofani"};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Sorting is a very common operation, surely you can find enough information online to make an attempt?

Comment: @Jon: correct would be "have you tried anything"?

Comment: You have neither an array list or a list, just an array. Also, why do you *want to sort the array list to find out the same last names*? What has this to do with sorting?

Comment: @Vlad: The benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] iniArray = { "M Facci", "D Thornton", "B Luke", "S Tofani", "T Luke" };
var sortedArray = iniArray.OrderBy(r => r.Split(' ').Last()).ToArray();
```

or (courtesy @killercam)

```
var sortedArray = iniArray.OrderBy(r => r.Split().Last()).ToArray();
```

*Assuming there is only First Name and Last Name in a string, also, there exists a Last Name.*

To display the resulted array:

```
foreach (string str in sortedArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Output would be:

```
M Facci
B Luke
T Luke
D Thornton
S Tofani
```

Comment: I doubt the assumption is sound: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Vlad, yeah that is true, but I was only considering the sample in the question, also something left for the OP to do itself

Comment: You actually dont need the `' '` in the `Split()`...

Comment: @Killercam, nice, didn't know about that

Comment: Thank you for your answer and please let me know how to display the output in Winforms line by line.